# How to save empty form field as null?

Tags: php

I have a html form that sends POST data to php file.
In php I'm making a query to mysql database. In database I have int column that accept null.

The problem is when web form field is empty, I want to save null to database.
I tried to make check before building the query

```
if (empty($licence))
        $sql_query.="null,r1=";
    else $sql_query.="'".$_POST["licence"]."',r1=";
```

It's working. But if user write 0 in the form field, in database will be saved null, which is wrong. If user entered 0, I want to save 0, but if the field is empty I want to save null. How to fix this??
The problem is that if field is empty, 0 will be send as post data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function(PHP Manual)

Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

In your case, use:

```
if (!strlen($licence))
    $sql_query.="null,r1=";
else $sql_query.="'".$_POST["licence"]."',r1=";
```

instead

Comment: The problem is that if field is empty, 0 will be send as post data...My wish is to save 0, if user entered it and save null if field is empty..

Comment: No, it won't. If the field was empty, an empty string would be sent as POST data. **Unless** your framework does some additional processing(e.g. JavaScript which replaces empty form fields it deems numerical with 0's) or PHP code which does the same, an empty field will be received as an empty string. Then you can use my code to achieve your results.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql_query.=($_POST["licence"]?"'".$_POST["licence"]."'":NULL).",r1=";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have licence field default value as 0 in database table. Therefore when the field is empty, it takes 0 while saving record into database.

Make default value as NULL.It will clear issue.

Answer (score -1):

if you check empty(0) you will get false (as described in the manual)

```
if (isset($licence) && empty($licence)) {
    // it is empty or 0
} elseif(isset($licence)) {
    // it is something 
}
```

Comment: That won't work for an empty string. For both "" and "0" it will enter the **if** branch, which the OP clearly doesn't want. Since he is receiving data by POST, when the user doesn't input data in a field, he will be receiving an empty string.

Comment: you are right, somehow i thought he wanted 0 as NULL, need more coffee :-)

Comment: Vlad is correct. I want 0 in database if user entered 0, but if user entered nothing I want null...
The problem is that the both empty and 0 in the field sending 0 as POST data..